# Type Inference for Map in Scala

Tags: scala

It seems that Scala `Set`/`Map` can result in weird type inference.

For example, in the REPL:

```
$ val m2 = Map("foo" -> Map("bar" -> 6), "baz" -> Map.empty)
> scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[_ <: String, Int]] = Map(foo -> Map(bar -> 6), baz -> Map())
```

I know about some `CanBuildFrom` and "defaults" can result in a `immutable.Map` type.

However, why is it `...Map[_ <: String, Int]` rather than a `...Map[String, Int]`?

**Observations**:

`m1` defined below is inferred as expected.

```
$ val m1 = Map("foo" -> Map("bar" -> 5))
> scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]] = Map(foo -> Map(bar -> 5))
```

By explicit type ascription, both can be converted "correctly" (I think this is due to `CanBuildFrom`):

```
val _m1: Map[String, Map[String, Int]] = Map("foo" -> Map("bar" -> 5))
val _m2: Map[String, Map[String, Int]] = Map("foo" -> Map("bar" -> 6), "baz" -> Map.empty)
```

I care about this since when I use some functional libraries, e.g., `cats`, I have to make sure both operands are of the same type and I like to know *when* I should use type ascription. For example,

```
import cats.Semigroup
import cats.implicits._
m1 ++ m2 // works
m1 |+| m2 // error
// found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[_ <: String, Int]]
// required: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no `CanBuildFrom`s at work here, only the invariance of `Map` keys.

When you write:

```
Map("foo" -> Map("bar" -> 6), "baz" -> Map.empty)
```

The compiler tries to infer the type of this, and in doing so it needs to figure out the common type of `Map("bar" -> 6)` and `Map.empty`--the *least upper-bound*.

`Map.empty` is a `Map[Nothing, Nothing]` if you do not supply type parameters, so the compiler computes the least upper-bound of `Map[String, Int]` and `Map[Nothing, Nothing]`, and it comes up with the *existential type* `Map[_ <: String, Int]`.  This is because `Map` is *invariant* over its first type parameter. (a `Map[Nothing, Int]` is not a `Map[String, Int]`)

It works when you add the type annotation because you're adding a hint in which the compiler uses to infer the type parameters of `Map.empty`. Without the hint, it happily uses `Map[Nothing, Nothing]`, instead. Is this a slight deficiency in type inference? Maybe. I always prefer to provide the type parameters of `CollectionType.empty` just to be safe.

```
val m2 = Map("foo" -> Map("bar" -> 6), "baz" -> Map.empty[String, Int])
```

Comment: May I know why lup of `Map[String, Int]` and `Map[Nothing, Nothing]` is the existential type `Map[_ <: String, Int]`?

Comment: It's easier to see how the compiler constructs the LUB as an existential type if you make the other map a `Map[Int, Int]` or something other than nothing. You get `_ >: String with SomeOtherType` where `SomeOtherType` is the incompatible type the compiler is trying to cram into something useful. With `Nothing` String with Nothing` is just `String`,  The compiler replaces `String with Nothing` with `String`.

Comment: but that's different, at least the direction is inversed?

Comment: Likely because there is only one type there. With other type combinations, the existential type couldn't possibly by a sub-type of the compound of them all.